# Rails error form fields validation css and semantic-ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am facing a problem with errors during form validation.

### How semantic-ui shows errors

```
 <div class="field error">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown">
      <div class="default text">Select</div>
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <input type="hidden" name="gender">
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="male">Male</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="female">Female</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see it places `.error`css class at the container.

### How rails shows errors

```
Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  %Q(<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>).html_safe
end
```

Rails wraps the form field (input,textarea,select etc) with a div with `field_with_errors` class.

Even customizing this at app.config I see no way changing the parent's css. Is there is any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem and found zero convenient solutions to it.

Solved it by doing the following things:

First of all, in any view I want to have the error class applied to the `.fields` div I've added the following line at the end:

**new.html.erb** (for example)

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/fields_error_class', locals: {model: @user} %>
```

Next, create the following partial: **/shared/_fields_error_class.html.erb**:

```
<% class_name = model.class.name.downcase %>
<% field_selectors = [] %>
<% model.errors.keys.each do |field| %>
    <% field_selectors.push "##{class_name}_#{field}" if model.errors[field].any? %>
<% end %>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
    $("<%= field_selectors.join(',') %>").parents('.field').addClass('error');
<% end %>
```

I hope my solution is self explanatory and will help others who struggle with semantic-ui and rails.

Comment: we did something like that. However the real solution would be to use a custom form builder

Comment: Or better, use `<% class_name = model.class.name.underscore %>` so you get camel_case for CamelCase.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 and HTML5 **without** JQuery, replace the partial in the original solution with:

```
<% class_name = model.class.name.downcase %>
<% model.errors.keys.each do |field| %>
    <% if model.errors[field].any? %>
      <%= javascript_tag do %>
        document.getElementById('<%= "#{class_name}_#{field}" %>').parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('error');
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also, add the following file to Rails 5:

```
# initializers/customize_errors.rb
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance_tag|
  # gets rid of field_with_errors div being applied to fields
  html_tag
end
```